# Insert one-hot along with other data types

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have data with attributes of numerical and categorical types in one row. Numerical values after normalization will be in the range of 0 - 1, float type. There are also some continuous data, also float type.
How can I insert both **float** and **one-hot-vector** (categorical) data into some Keras layer as one row of data?

Example expected row of data:

```
[float, float, float, [one-hot-vector]]

[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, [0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: Just concatenate them.

Comment: One hot vectors really just represent a bunch of features, so you can put them in normally [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 1]. The pandas library has a function called get_dumies which should help you.

Comment: Following dr. Snoopy's advice - concatenation did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get Dummies or Categorical Codes.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Year': 2020, 'Airport':2000, 'Casino':5000, 'Stadium':9000, 'Size':'Small'}, 
       {'Year': 2019, 'Airport':3000, 'Casino':4000, 'Stadium':12000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2018, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':9000, 'Stadium':10000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2017, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':10000, 'Stadium':15000, 'Size':'Large'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df

df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
df_fin
```

[image]

One-Hot-Encoding has the advantage that the result is binary rather than ordinal and that everything sits in an orthogonal vector space. The disadvantage is that for high cardinality, the feature space can really blow up quickly and you start fighting with the curse of dimensionality. You can use PCA after OHE!